# Laravel php artisan migrate nothing to migrate

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm using Laravel 5.4

This is my migration files:

[image]

When I run `php artisan migrate`

> Nothing to migrate.

When I run `php artisan migrate:reset`

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'webinfluence.influencer_profil' (SQL: drop table `influencer_profil`)

I deleted all tables

Comment: To remove the `nothing to migrate` error, delete rows in the migrations table. `Base table or view not found` error is occurring because you were deleted those tables and in your migration `down()` method laravel tries to delete the table which is not present in the db.You may add  `Schema::dropIfExists('table_name');` in your down() method of migration to fix this.

Comment: Yes I was going to edit my post
When I changed `drop()` to `dropIfExists()` everything goes back in order.